# Error and warning when modeling count data using glmmTMB

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to fit zero inflated poisson random effects model with count data using glmmTMB. However, I received some errors and warnings.

```
head(data)

  count time study    
1     0  259     1 
2     0  199     1 
3     0  571     1 
4     0  927     1 
5     7  254     1 
6     0  877     1 

str(data)

 'data.frame':  959 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ count : int  0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ time  : int  259 199 571 927 254 877 555 158 1014 705 ...
 $ study : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

time is an offset term, and study is a random effect I have to add.

**Error 1**

If I add a random effect, then the following random-effect models report the same error

```
f1<-glmmTMB(count~1+offset(time)+1|study, data = data, family = poisson, ziformula = ~1|study)

f2<-glmmTMB(count~1+offset(time)+1|study, data = subset(data, study=="1"), family = poisson, ziformula = ~1|study)

NA/NaN function evaluationError in nlminb(start = par, objective = fn, gradient = gr, control = control$optCtrl) : 
 gradient function must return a numeric vector of length 4
```

**Error 2**

I thought I need to try a simpler model, and thus I dropped the random-effect. Unfortunately, I received a different error.

```
f3<-glmmTMB(count~1+offset(time), data = data, family = poisson, ziformula = ~1)

f4<-glmmTMB(count~1+offset(time), data = subset(data, study=="1"), family = poisson, ziformula = ~1)

NA/NaN function evaluationError in nlminb(start = par, objective = fn, gradient = gr, control = control$optCtrl) : 
  NA/NaN gradient evaluation
```

**Warning 1**

OK. I wonder how I can get an output without any error. So, I dropped the offset term instead of the random-effect, and thus obtained a warning instead of an error.

```
f5<-glmmTMB(count~1+1|study, data = data, family = poisson, ziformula = ~1|study)

f6<-glmmTMB(count~1+1|study, data = subset(data, study=="1"), family = poisson, ziformula = ~1|study)

Cholmod warning 'matrix not positive definite' at file ../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c, line 729Cholmod warning 'matrix not positive definite' at file ../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c, line 729Cholmod warning 'matrix not positive definite' at file ../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c, line 729Cholmod warning 'matrix not positive definite' at file ../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c, line 729Cholmod warning 'matrix not positive definite' at file ../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c, line 729Cholmod warning 'matrix not positive definite' at file ../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c, line 729Cholmod warning 'matrix not positive definite' at file ../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c, line 729Cholmod warning 'matrix not positive definite' at file ../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c, line 729
```

**"Good" fit with neither error nor warning**

After a bunch of refits, I find that if I drop at least one of two random-effect terms and the offset term, models will report neither an error or a warning.

```
f7<-glmmTMB(count~1+1|study, data = data, family = poisson, ziformula = ~1)

f8<-glmmTMB(count~1, data = data, family = poisson, ziformula = ~1|study)
```

**Question**

What issues caused these errors and warining? If possible, how could I fit a ZIP mixed effect model and receive neither error nor warning?

**Example**

I have a reproducible example which produced the **warning 1**

```
count.ex<-rpois(500, 0.2)
study.ex<-as.factor(sample(1:5, 500, replace = TRUE))
time.ex<-rexp(500, 150)

fit.ex<-glmmTMB(count.ex~1+offset(time.ex)+1|study.ex, family = poisson, ziformula = ~1|study.ex)

Cholmod warning 'matrix not positive definite' at file ../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c, line 729Cholmod warning 'matrix not positive definite' at file ../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c, line 729Cholmod warning 'matrix not positive definite' at file ../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c, line 729Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather difficult without a reproducible example!

- There is one obvious problem with your model: you've specified `offset(time)` in your model, you almost certainly want to use `offset(log(time))`.  Your `time` values are large (the values I can see in your `str()` range from 500-1000; the offset enters the *predicted* value in the model as `exp(offset)`, which is either ridiculously large (if `offset < log(.Machine$double.xmax) == 709.78`) or infinite.
- You should be careful to protect random-effect terms with parentheses (e.g. you use `~1 + 1|study` rather than `~1 + (1|study)`; I don't think it causes problems in the examples you show here, but in general the pipe (`|`) operator has low precedence, which means that e.g. `~1+a+b|study` is equivalent to `~(1+a+b)|study` ...

If I use

```
 ~count.ex~1+offset(log(time.ex))+(1|study.ex)
```

in your example, I don't get any warnings.

Comment: It works! Cannot believe I made such silly mistake. Thank you so much!