# zero-inflated overdispersed count data glmmTMB error in R

Tags: r, convergence, standardized, glmmtmb

I am working with count data (available [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d)) that are zero-inflated and overdispersed and has random effects. The package best suited to work with this sort of data is the `glmmTMB` (details [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/glmmTMB.pdf) and troubleshooting [here](http://127.0.0.1:23146/library/glmmTMB/doc/troubleshooting.html)).

Before working with the data, I inspected it for normality (it is zero-inflated), homogeneity of variance, correlations, and outliers. The data had two outliers, which I removed from the dataset linekd above. There are 351 observations from 18 locations (`prop_id`).

The data looks like this:

```
euc0 ea_grass ep_grass np_grass np_other_grass month year precip season   prop_id quad
 3      5.7      0.0     16.7            4.0     7 2006    526 Winter    Barlow    1
 0      6.7      0.0     28.3            0.0     7 2006    525 Winter    Barlow    2
 0      2.3      0.0      3.3            0.0     7 2006    524 Winter    Barlow    3
 0      1.7      0.0     13.3            0.0     7 2006    845 Winter    Blaber    4
 0      5.7      0.0     45.0            0.0     7 2006    817 Winter    Blaber    5
 0     11.7      1.7     46.7            0.0     7 2006    607 Winter    DClark    3
```

The response variable is `euc0` and the random effects are `prop_id` and `quad_id`. The rest of the variables are fixed effects (all representing the percent cover of different plant species).

The model I want to run:

```
library(glmmTMB)
seed0<-glmmTMB(euc0 ~ ea_grass + ep_grass + np_grass + np_other_grass + month + year*precip + season*precip + (1|prop_id)  + (1|quad), data = euc, family=poisson(link=identity))

fit_zinbinom <- update(seed0,family=nbinom2) #allow variance increases quadratically
```

The error I get after running the `seed0` code is:

> Error in optimHess(par.fixed, obj$fn, obj$gr) :    gradient in optim
>   evaluated to length 1 not 15 In addition: There were 50 or more
>   warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

`warnings()` gives:

```
1. In (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  ... :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
```

I also normally mean center and standardize my numerical variables, but this only removes the first error and keeps the `NA/NaN` error. I tried adding a `glmmTMBControl` statement like [this OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959854/error-and-warning-when-modeling-count-data-using-glmmtmb), but it just opened a whole new world of errors.

**How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?**

A detailed explanation would be appreciated so that I can learn how to troubleshoot this better myself in the future. *Alternatively*, I am open to a `MCMCglmm` solution as that function can also deal with this sort of data (despite taking longer to run).

Comment: Do you have a strong reason to use an identity-link Poisson?  In general, link functions (or specifically inverse-link functions) that don't restrict the response-scale predictions to the domain of the response distribution are computationally tricky.

Comment: can you say which observations you identified as outliers?  The one with `euc0==78` looks suspicious; which other one?

Comment: @BenBolker The two outliers would be the `euc0==78` and `np_other_grass==20`. I landed on using the identity link, after reading the troubleshooting document ("If you’re using a non-identity link function (e.g. log, logit), then parameter values with |β|>10 are suspect (for a logit link, this implies probabilities very close to 0 or 1; for a log link, this implies mean counts that are close to 0 or extremely large)." I am not well versed enough with the link functions though, so I usually leave them as their default (and changed it originally because of these errors.

Comment: yeah, that wasn't the right solution ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An incomplete answer ...

- identity-link models for limited-domain response distributions (e.g. Gamma or Poisson, where negative values are impossible) are computationally problematic; in my opinion they're often conceptually problematic as well, although there are some reasonable arguments in their favor. Do you have a good reason to do this?
- This is a pretty small data set for the model you're trying to fit: 13 fixed-effect predictors and 2 random-effect predictors. The rule of thumb would be that you want about 10-20 times that many observations: that *seems* to fit in OK with your 345 or so observations, but ... only 40 of your observations are non-zero! That means your 'effective' number of observations/amount of information will be much smaller (see Frank Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies* for more discussion of this point).

That said, let me run through some of the things I tried and where I ended up.

- `GGally::ggpairs(euc, columns=2:10)` doesn't detect anything obviously terrible about the data (I did throw out the data point with `euc0==78`)

In order to try to make the identity-link model work I added some code in glmmTMB.  You should be able to install via `remotes::install_github("glmmTMB/glmmTMB/glmmTMB@clamp")` (note you will need compilers etc. installed to install this).  This version takes negative predicted values and forces them to be non-negative, while adding a corresponding penalty to the negative log-likelihood.

Using the new version of glmmTMB I don't get an error, but I do get these warnings:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
>     Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')
>   2: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
>     Model convergence problem; false convergence (8). See vignette('troubleshooting')

The Hessian (second-derivative) matrix being non-positive-definite means there are some (still hard-to-troubleshoot) problems. `heatmap(vcov(f2)$cond,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA)` lets me look at the covariance matrix. (I also like `corrplot::corrplot.mixed(cov2cor(vcov(f2)$cond),"ellipse","number")`, but that doesn't work when `vcov(.)$cond` is non-positive definite. In a pinch you can use `sfsmisc::posdefify()` to force it to be positive definite ...)

Tried scaling:

```
eucsc <- dplyr::mutate_at(euc1,dplyr::vars(c(ea_grass:precip)), ~c(scale(.)))
```

This will help some - right now we're still doing a few silly things like treating year as a numeric variable without centering it (so the 'intercept' of the model is at year 0 of the Gregorian calendar ...)

But that still doesn't fix the problem.

Looking more closely at the `ggpairs` plot, it looks like `season` and `year` are confounded: `with(eucsc,table(season,year))` shows that observations occur in Spring and Winter in one year and Autumn in the other year. `season` and `month` are also confounded: if we know the month, then we automatically know the season.

At this point I decided to give up on the identity link and see what happened.  `update(<previous_model>, family=poisson)` (i.e. using a Poisson with a standard log link) worked!  So did using `family=nbinom2`, which was much better.

I looked at the results and discovered that the CIs for the precip X season coefficients were crazy, so dropped the interaction term (`update(f2S_noyr_logNB, . ~ . - precip:season)`)  at which point the results look sensible.

A few final notes:

- the variance associated with quadrat is effectively zero
- I don't think you necessarily need zero-inflation; low means and overdispersion (i.e. `family=nbinom2`) are probably sufficient.
- the distribution of the residuals looks OK, but there still seems to be some model mis-fit (`library(DHARMa); plot(simulateResiduals(f2S_noyr_logNB2))`).  I would spend some time plotting residuals and predicted values against various combinations of predictors to see if you can localize the problem.

PS A quicker way to see that there's something wrong with the fixed effects (multicollinearity):

```
X <- model.matrix(~ ea_grass + ep_grass +
                   np_grass + np_other_grass + month +
                   year*precip + season*precip,
                  data=euc)
ncol(X)  ## 13
Matrix::rankMatrix(X) ## 11
```

`lme4` has tests like this, and machinery for automatically dropping aliased columns, but they aren't implemented in `glmmTMB` at present.

Comment: One follow-up question: do you know why `glmmTMB` and `glmer` would have different outputs/results when `family=nbinom2`?

Comment: `glmer` can't do `family=nbinom2`.  Do you mean `glmer.nb`?  If this is an overfitted/unstable model, it wouldn't surprise me greatly if `glmer.nb` and `glmmTMB` got somewhat different answers.  Compare parameter estimates including SEs/confidence intervals; compare log-likelihoods ...

Comment: Yes! That would do it! The CI's were quite large for the `glmer.nb` model. Thank you!